# ValueNotifier Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, mobile

I keep getting

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

on the code line

```
notificationtext.value =(jsonResponse['data']['content']);
```

and for the api response

```
{"err": 0, "data": [{"id": 1, "content": "Good Morning"}]}
```

can someone explain the reason and a fix for this line of code.

```
final ValueNotifier<String>  notificationtext=ValueNotifier<String>("");


  Future getNotification()async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var sid= sharedPreferences.getString("sid");

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  'sid':'$sid',
};
var response = await http.get(Url,headers:headers
);
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  if(jsonResponse['err']==0){
    notificationtext.value =(jsonResponse['data']['content']);
    print(notificationtext.value );
  }
}else{
  print("Not working");
}


 }

  Container  notificationContent(){
    return Container(
      decoration:BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      child:ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notificationtext,
      builder:(context,value, widget){
          if(value==""){
          return Text("Loading");
          }else{
          return Text(value);
          }
    },
    )
    );
  }
```

Comment: try this jsonResponse['data'][0]['content']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notificationtext.value =(jsonResponse['data'][0]['content']);
```

Kei Credo answer . i dont know how to upvote your answer in the comment.